# Installing Debian 10 on NVIDIA Jetson Nano

Tags: debian, nvidia

We are evaluating NVIDIA Jetson Nano and being Debian our preferred Linux flavor we are wondering if anyone has made any progress in this direction (Install Debian). We found some approach with Debian 9 detailed in this link [Installing Debian 9 on NVIDIA Jetson Nano](https://gglabs.us/node/2060) but we haven't found any additional information in this regard. The link also gives the impression that the project has been discontinued.

Does anyone see any chances that a Debian build for this platform will be available in the near future?

Any recommendation on whether we should abandon the idea or instead continue in this direction?

Any suggestions on where to investigate further?

Any recommendation or suggestion will be certainly welcome.

Comment: *Does anyone see any chances that an official Debian build for this platform will be available in the near future?* You mean without any of the closed-source nvidia drivers that make the Jetson Nano what it is?

Comment: Thank you @MarcusMüller I have remove the word official from my question. Yes, including the Nvidia drivers. Similar to what NVIDIA provides with Ubuntu